# gdal_translate error: Could not perform Read/Write (ecw to tif)

Tags: linux, tiff, gdal

Thanks in advance for any help!

I am using the gdal CLI for ECW file conversions to subset and convert a large ECW file to individual tif files. I have two ECW files, one infrared and one RGB. on the RGB file, the following code works perfectly:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -projwin 101000.0 444000.0 101750.0  443250.0 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co TILED=YES -co predictor=2 2023_PLRR_tm_hr_RGB_o.ecw test.ecw
```

However, when I run the same function on the infrared file, I get the following, non-helpful error:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -projwin 101000.0 444000.0 101750.0  443250.0 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co TILED=YES -co predictor=2 2022_PLRR_tm_hr_CIR_o.ecw test.ecw
Input file size is 420000, 360000
0ERROR 1: Could not perform Read/Write on file
```

I already checked file permissions on linux, and they are the same:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3747269425 Mar  1 13:04 2023_PLRR_tm_hr_RGB_o.ecw
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         36 Mar  1 13:05 2022_PLRR_tm_hr_CIR_o.eww
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1071260823 Mar  1 13:06 2022_PLRR_tm_hr_CIR_w.ecw
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         36 Mar  1 13:07 2022_PLRR_tm_hr_CIR_w.eww
```

the only function that works on both is pdalinfo. I tried pdal_warp (since the infrared file had a missing CRS according to pdalinfo, I tried setting it) but got the same error.